# Jquery scrollbar issues - Resizing window or opening Firebug solves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I have a really odd problem that i have spent hours trying to fix but am getting nowhere.

I have a jQuery scroll-pane on my website that allows you to scroll thorugh various products. When the page loads none of the products are showing. However, when you resize the browser window slightly or open/close firebug, the products pop into view and display correctly.

[An example can be found here](http://www.scifinow.co.uk/?p=331122&preview=true).

Comment: Your link seems to go to a 404

Comment: The scrollpane appears on the 404 page. It has a red ribbon on it saying 'Love technology try...'

Comment: turn on Firebug, switch the tab to "Console" and then reload the page, many errors come up there, try to fix them one by one, this may fix your problem...

Comment: Ah :) can you post the jQuery code you have which initialises the scrollpane.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. It can be caused by removing parent element after detach.

```
var $img = $("<img>").attr.......
// ---- loading
$parent.append($img);
var w = $img.naturalWidth....
$img.detach();
$parent.remove();
$anotherDiv.append($img);
```

A black square is rendered while data on the graphic card aren´t updated. I've solved my problem by detaching $parent instead of removing.